# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

i would like to join 3 tables by using @ManyToMany , I have 2 entities "user" and "roles"  ,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTD3i.png)

but it's  gives me as an error  :

Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.demo.User.roles[com.example.demo.Role]

THe "user" entity :

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    //pour l'auto-incrémentation de la clé primaire
    ////Strategy = GenerationType. IDENTITY : La génération de la clé primaire se fera à partir d’une Identité propre au SGBD. 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id ; 

   private String full_name;
   private String password ; 
   private boolean enabled ;
   private boolean email ;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   //pour connecter les tables
   @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
            )
   private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
   
public String getUsername() {

    return full_name ;
}
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
public boolean isEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(boolean email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public void setUsername(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
} 
}
```

the "roles" entity :

```
package com.example.demo;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
     
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>

        </dependency>
    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the stack traces :

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _   
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \  
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \ 
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-03-24 16:37:55.741  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-3TAPOK7 with 
PID 3784 (E:\Stage\demo\target\classes started by Dell in E:\Stage\demo)
2021-03-24 16:37:55.743  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-24 16:37:55.798  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-03-24 16:37:55.799  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-03-24 16:37:56.411  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-24 16:37:56.464  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 41 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-24 16:37:57.087  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-03-24 16:37:57.105  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-24 16:37:57.105  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-03-24 16:37:57.224  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-24 16:37:57.224  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1425 ms
2021-03-24 16:37:57.404  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-24 16:37:57.461  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-03-24 16:37:57.569  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-03-24 16:37:57.642  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-24 16:37:57.725  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-24 16:37:57.781  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect2021-03-24 16:37:57.967 ERROR 3784 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.demo.User.roles[com.example.demo.Role]
2021-03-24 16:37:57.967  WARN 3784 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of 
@OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.demo.User.roles[com.example.demo.Role]
2021-03-24 16:37:57.976  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-03-24 16:37:58.013  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-03-24 16:37:58.016  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-03-24 16:37:58.028  INFO 3784 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-24 16:37:58.046 ERROR 3784 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.demo.User.roles[com.example.demo.Role]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.demo.User.roles[com.example.demo.Role]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1351) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:874) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]     
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) 
~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]    
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

[mvn spring-boot:r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H4Ss.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any issue. Can you please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i added it

Comment: I still can't see any problem. What happens if you execute mvn spring-boot:run ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i added  a screenshot  in the end of my post

Comment: As I can see you don't execute it where the pom.xml is

Comment: In the meantime, are you sure both entities are in the same source folder?